# GoDoc Identifier search browser interface

Tags: google-chrome, go, godoc

I accidentally got to this UI when hitting some keys, but I don't remember what I pressed. What keys do I need to bring up this interface?

[image: Id search]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typed "F" to bring up this interface. Type "?" for documentation on all keyboard shortcuts.

See https://godoc.org/-/about for information about more features.